Adding value in list c#
I have got some line of
requestParams.OutParamList = new List<ParamsList>() {
    new ParamsList() {Name = OutParamName}
};

I found this code from my solution and did not understand how it's working and basic syntax of this code writing

This is a combination of collection and property initialisers.
See documentation for lots more details.
The key to understanding here is to break down things from the inside out. First inside:
new ParamsList() {Name = OutParamName}

is creating an instance of ParamsList and initialising its Name property with the value of OutParamValue.
Around this then there is:
new List<ParamsList>() {
    expression
};

is creating a List<T> collection specialised to ParamsList initialising the collection with a single value that is the result of expression which is covered above.

So all this code is doing is:
Creating a new list called OutParamList inside the requestParams object.
This list is designed to store objects of type ParamsList.
It then immediately adds one new ParamsList object to the list, and this object has its Name property set to the value of OutParamName.
Essentially, it's initialising a list with one item, where that item is a customised ParamsList object.
As to why, let's say you have a method that executes a database query, and you need to pass different parameters to the query based on the user's input or other conditions.
ParamsList in this context could represent a class that stores information about each parameter (like the name of the parameter and its value). The OutParamList is a list that holds these parameter objects and is used to dynamically manage which parameters are passed to a query.
This way allows you to easily add, remove, or modify parameters without changing the method signatures or the core logic of your database operations.
You can use the same list and classes (ParamsList and requestParams) across different parts of your application, which makes the code more maintainable and consistent.
